# How to modify a global large array in a function

Tags: functions

Assuming variable x is a long list, which needs 1GB memory to store.

I want to modify x in a function, such as let x[[10]]=1, using

```
f[a_,i_]:=Block[{b},b=a;b[[i]]=1;b]
x=f[x,10]
```

but when I call the funtion f, it will take extra 1GB memory.
How can I in-situ modify x in function f without extra memory?

Comment: `SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]; foo[a_, i_]:=a[[i]] = 1`?

Comment: @Kuba it works well! thank you.

Comment: Additional reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/5478